# OR Operation in JOINS SQL(MYSQL)

Tags: mysql

I am using MYSQL

```
SELECT  m.proposalId, m.title, n.stageNumber, n.committeeId, n.modifiedDate,
        o.msNumber , o.description,o.ics,o.edition
    FROM  mystands_Proposal m
    INNER join  mystands_ProjectLifecycle n on m.proposalId = n.proposalId
    INNER join  mystands_Project o          on m.proposalId = o.proposalId
    WHERE  n.newState=0
      AND  n.committeeId=79827
      AND  (n.assignedTo=29913 OR  n.actionBy=29913 )
      AND  n.proposalId LIKE '%sdas%'
      AND  o.projectNumber LIKE '%sdass%'
      AND  n.stageNumber=40.92
      AND  o.category=1
      AND  o.degreeofCorrespondence=1
      AND  o.msNumber LIKE '%sdas%'
      AND  (n.modifiedDate <='2015-05-15' AND  n.stageNumber=40.2 )
      AND  (n.modifiedDate <='2015-05-07' AND  n.stageNumber=30.99 )
      AND  (n.modifiedDate <='2015-05-27' AND  n.stageNumber=55.99 )
```

I am doing inner joins for three tables for search functionality and in java if the user enters the values then I am appending the value to the sql query on the fly. The above code is working fine for AND operations between fields.

How do I perform "OR" operation for the fields entered by the user and display the result. I have tried this:

```
SELECT m.proposalId, m.title, n.stageNumber, n.committeeId, n.modifiedDate, o.msNumber , o.description,o.ics,o.edition FROM mystands_Proposal m 
INNER join  
    mystands_ProjectLifecycle n on m.proposalId = n.proposalId 
INNER join
    mystands_Project o on m.proposalId = o.proposalId  
WHERE n.newState=0
      OR  n.committeeId=80246
      OR  (n.assignedTo=79977
              OR  n.actionBy=79977
          )
      OR  n.proposalId LIKE '%ads%'
      OR  o.projectNumber LIKE '%sds%'
      OR  n.stageNumber=30.99
      OR  o.category=1
      OR  o.degreeofCorrespondence=1
      OR  o.msNumber LIKE '%sadsa%'
      OR  (n.modifiedDate <='2015-05-22'
              AND  n.stageNumber=40.2
          )
      OR  (n.modifiedDate <='2015-05-22'
              AND  n.stageNumber=30.99
          )
      OR  (n.modifiedDate <='2015-05-29'
              AND  n.stageNumber=55.99
          )
```

Now what is happening is it is giving me the results of the inner joins because newState=0 is true and entire where condition is getting true and I am getting the results of inner joins on three table and the result is not being filtered as desired.

Can you please help where am going wrong? Thanks.

Comment: In this where clause `WHERE 
    n.newState=0      OR n.committeeId=80246 OR (n.assignedTo=79977 OR n.actionBy=79977) OR n.proposalId LIKE '%ads%' OR o.projectNumber LIKE '%sds%' OR n.stageNumber=30.99 OR o.category=1 OR o.degreeofCorrespondence=1 OR o.msNumber LIKE '%sadsa%' OR (n.modifiedDate <='2015-05-22' AND n.stageNumber=40.2) OR (n.modifiedDate <='2015-05-22' AND n.stageNumber=30.99) OR (n.modifiedDate <='2015-05-29' AND n.stageNumber=55.99) ' its appear the result will be always true even if all other conditions are false since the result of OR will be true

Comment: if at least one of the condition is true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If n.newState=0 is always true then just remove it from your where statement.

or if everything you want to return needs to have that true then just change your first OR to a AND.
Then it will check to make sure that it is true and one other thing in your where statement is also true.

```
WHERE n.newState=0 AND ([all your other OR conditions])
```